# Converting react native app into native android dependency/library

Tags: android, react-native

I would like to transform my react native app into a library that can be added as a dependency/library by any already existing native Android project through gradle.Is this possible?

Comment: Guys come on instead of down voting at least try to say something, I really would appreciate any response. Let me simplify my question. I do have an application that is built on react native but my current desire is to make it available to be used as a third party library that can be used by any other regular android project. For example, the same way you can import and use facebook sdk in your normal Android project.Thanks

Comment: What is the latest with this? I'm facing a similar scenario - package React Native dependencies and built output .js into a library. Then that library may be referenced by a vanilla android app. I've had to achieve a similar process for iOS and this article helped there http://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/04/17/making-a-components-pod/

Comment: Please share steps for this

Answer (score 0):

First publish your react native source code in Your github and after copy that project page url and publish it on gitPack ,
Now finally from there you will recieve your dependency

Happy coding :)